# Get all dates by month in android database

Tags: android, sqlite

I have `table` in `database` where one of `column` is for `date in Long`. **Is there any simple way to get all dates by month?** For example I need all dates for October. For day I use:

```
public static List<Plan> getPlanListByMonth(SQLiteDatabase db, DateTime date) {

        String where = "date" + " = '"+ "2015-11-04" +"'";

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, null, where,
                null, null, null, null, null);

        return getPlanList(cursor);
}
```

but I have no idea how to create **where** condition to get all values by month.

Comment: Tip: This `String where = "date" + " = '"+ "2015-11-04" +"'";` is MUCH SLOWER than this `String where = "date = '2015-11-04'";`. Because of string concatenations, which are expensive.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein and actually it should be: `String where = "date = ?"`

Comment: @pskink Yes, even better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [strftime()](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) function

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE strftime('%m', 'date') = '11'
```